# Hold down to view video like snapchat in swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a `TableView` that for each cell a user can hold down to view a video/image. The holding down part works but when I release it doesn't go back to the `TableView`.
Heres the code for presenting the view with the video/image:

```
func playVideo() {
    // get path and url of movie
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("static2", ofType:"mov")
    println(path)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var moviePlayer = MPViewController()//took out video handling right now so this is just basically a regular view controller
    moviePlayer.navController = self.navigationController
    // construct the views
    moviePlayer.addGestRecognizer()

    self.navigationController.pushViewController(moviePlayer, animated: true)
}
```

and then I have this gesture recognizer added to the view cell:

```
let singleTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapped:"))
self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

and here is the "tapped:" function:

```
func tapped(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    println("held down")
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        playVideo()
    }
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        println("hold ended")
        self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    //playVideo()
}
```

for some reason once I push the view controller onto the main navigationController I no longer get the "hold ended".  How can I set this up so it works exactly like snapchat?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to present the media with a UIView instead of a UIViewController?

Comment: would I use the navigation controller to do that... all this code is in a subclass of uitableviewcell

Comment: Oh that makes sense...but still you could just create a `UIView` filling the whole screen. I don't use Snapchat but I think thats how it works there as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly, MPMovieplayercontroller will add another view for displaying video, so that you gesture may change status to `.Cancelled` or `Failed`. You should change to use AVPlayer.

Comment: uiview worked really well thanks @LinusG. i'll update with the code later on

Comment: Cool! I put that as an answer so you can give me credit :P

Comment: @TylerRice, Do you mind sharing the updated code how you used UIView to play videos? I am working on somewhat similar and would like to see how you solved the problem. Some helps would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution for what you're asking but another idea, you might want to think about presenting the media files with a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController`.

Hope that helps :)